# Android studio Youtube videoplayer API Gradle build error status code 400: bad request

Tags: android, api, youtube

I wanted to use [this](https://pierfrancescosoffritti.github.io/android-youtube-player/) API to use the youtube videoplayer. However when i try to build the project after I put the code in dependencies it gives me this error, any idea how to get it working?
[Error Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xsaHl.png)

Answer (score 0):

implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:{latest-version}'

Version number is missing in your code

use this:

```
implementation 'com.pierfrancescosoffritti.androidyoutubeplayer:core:10.0.5'
```

Comment: Omg, i'm a huge idiot, didn't see the version missing. Thanks a lot my friend.